# How to style ng-zorro component with angular css component?

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

I have a certain problem, for example:

I don't like the margin on the ng-zorro table.
In my browser I can see that it gets the margin from `.ant-table-small>.ant-table-content>.ant-table-body` selector.

Is there some way to override it?

It doesn't exist in ng-zorro theme.less.
I am terribly sorry for this noob question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can override the Angular css by `::ng-deep` keyword, for example:

```css
::ng-deep .ant-table-small>.ant-table-content>.ant-table-body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
So whenever I need to style ng-zorro component, I use **::ng-deep**.
Tyty.

Comment: In this post you can learn about [Angular View Encapsulation](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change this style globally in your App(which likely you will), try to add a override css file and include it in the app's style file. So you don't need to repeat the same style override in each component.